# Is the set of elementary functions which do not have elementary integrals bigger than set of elementary functions which have elementary integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, elementary-set-theory, conjectures

It increasingly seems to me that the functions that have elementary integrals are quite rare in comparison to the ones that don't have them. Even raising an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) to a different power may result in it not having an elementary integral .

Ex. $\sqrt{\arctan (x)}$

Also many seemingly simple functions do not have elementary integrals.

Ex. $\frac {\sin (x)}{x}$ or $ \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) $

So my question is that can we write a formal proof to prove/disprove that the set of elementary functions which do not have elementary integrals is bigger than set of elementary functions which have elementary integrals?

Comment: I *think* the answer will vary depending on what functions you consider ‘elementary’. For example, if we consider polynomials to be the only elementary functions, then the set of elementary functions that do not have elementary integrals is empty.

Comment: As was noted by 雨が好きな人, you **must** define precisely what you mean by Elementary functions.

Comment: @uniquesolution edited it

Comment: If you allow arbitrary real constants, there are continuum-many elementary functions in total and there are continuum-many with elementary integrals (namely, the derivatives of elementary functions). If you allow only constants that are elementarily constructed (i.e., integers, thereby rationals and things like $e=\exp(1)$ or $\pi=4\arctan 1$) there are countably many elementary functions in total, and again there are countably many having an elementary integral.

Comment: The right approach here is probably analogous to the notion of natural density on integers: look at the fraction of elementary functions with bounded complexity which have elementary integrals, then take the limit as the complexity goes to infinity. Since most functions get more complex when you take their derivative, it seems likely that you're correct. But there are a lot of details I don't know how to fill in (and it's possible that the answer depends on exactly how you define "complexity").

Comment: @Micah I think it's likely that this will remain an open question and it will be pretty hard to write a formal proof for this. I think the best we can do for now is define "complexity" and use Risch's algorithm to test various functions with varying levels of complexity for elementary integrals

Comment: What do you mean when you ask if one set is "bigger"? Are you talking about cardinality or something else, such as a measure (if that can even be defined for a set of functions)?

Comment: @J.G. cardinality

Answer (score 2):

This might not answer your question precisely, but you might be interested by discussions around Liouville's theorem in differential algebra. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29?wprov=sfla1) is a link to the Wikipedia page of this theorem.

In a few words, the goal is to formalise the situation by saying that your "known" functions lie in some field $K$. For example, $K$ could be $\mathbb R(X)$ the field of rationnal fractions over $\mathbb R$. Then, adding some new functions like the logarithm is the same as looking at field extensions which have a certain property. I let you read that by yourself hoping that this might help you.

However I don't think this will answer your question fully, i.e. giving a way to take into account a comprehensive list of usual functions and then characterising perfectly those which integral is still some usual function.

Answer (score -5):

### They have the same cardinality

It is not clear whether all real/complex constants are allowed, or only integers. Let $K$ be the set of allowed constants.

Let $E_i$ and $E_{ni}$ be the sets of elementary functions that respectively do and don't have an elementary integral and let $E_a = E_i\ \cup\ E_{ni}$.

#### Lower bound on $E_i$ and $E_{ni}$

Since for every constant $c \in K$, there is a function $f(x) = c$, we have:
$$|E_i| \ge |K|$$
Also, for every constant $c \in K$, there is a function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)+c$, so:
$$|E_{ni}| \ge |K|$$

#### Upper bound on $E_a$ if $K = \mathbb{N}$

In this case every elementary function can be written using a text formula, for example `sin(2*x)^(x/3)`. If there were more than countable infinite elementary functions, this wouldn't be possible, so:

$$|E_{a}| \le |K|$$

#### Upper bound on $E_a$ if $K = \mathbb{R}$

Let's say a form of an elementary function is an elementary function with the constants written as $c_i$. So for example $c_1\cdot x^{c_2}$. Just as in the previous section, we can write every form as a text formula, like for example `c1*x^c2`. This gives an upper bound of $|\mathbb{N}|$ on the number of forms.

Now to go from a form to an elementary function, we have to fill in the constants. Let's say some form has $n$ constants, then there are $|\mathbb{R}|^n$ ways to choose the constants. It is  well known that $|\mathbb{R}|^n = |\mathbb{R}|$.

To get an upper bound on $E_a$, we can multiply the number of forms by the number of ways to choose constants. So $|\mathbb{N}| \cdot |\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}|$ and we get:

$$|E_{a}| \le |K|$$

#### Upper and lower bound combined

If $K = \mathbb{N}$ or $K = \mathbb{R}$ we proved these formulas to be true:
$$
\begin{align}
|E_i| &\ge |K| \\
|E_{ni}| &\ge |K| \\
|E_a| &\le |K| \\
|E_a| &= |E_i| + |E_{ni}|
\end{align}
$$
It's not hard to see that it follows that:
$$|E_{a}| = |E_i| = |E_{ni}| = |K|$$

Comment: So what is with all the downvotes? I understand it is not a complete proof. But the general idea is right, or not?